# How do I properly update global variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, export, global-variables, hoisting

I am using vue.js. I want a separate javascript method just for accessing a JSON from a url, then have an export method inside of that file for me to send the JSON to another file to manipulate accordingly.

```
var data;

function accessJSON(){

  //access JSON from url and store it inside global variable data
}

  //export function to access data
export function sendData(){
    return data;
}
```

I also tried exporting the data as a variable using something like

```
export var sendData = {
    output: data
 };
```

importing it accordingly using

```
import { sendData } from '/file.js'
```

and then `alert(sendData.send)` but this returns undefined.

If I export something like `output: "this is a test"` then it prints out and exports the variable perfectly, but it is causing problems when I try to export the global variable that I modify inside of a function.

I also tried using a test global var, declaring it and assigning it to `var globalVar = 2`, modifying globalVar to 8 inside of the method then exporting it and it exports `globalVar = 2` instead of `globalVar = 8` which means the var is not being properly updated when I modify it inside a function.

I believe it is because of hoisting but I don't understand how to avoid it as I saw that exporting/importing it or sending it to a function should have fixed it.

Comment: Your problem is *probably* that the `accessJSON()` function makes an asynchronous request, so `data` is only updated when that request completes.

Comment: @Pointy I moved the test globalVar = 8 to the very first line of the function before the request starts and it is still not being updated properly when I export it

Comment: Well the function version is almost certainly what you want to use. If you import that function and call it, it'll return the then-current value of `data`. What calls `accessJSON()`? It would help if you'd post more of the code context.

Comment: you're right, I apologize for not providing more info. Here is what I am trying to do: https://codesandbox.io/s/88ow75kqx0 for now I'd like to ignore trying to do this with JSON and focus on sending modified variables first inside test.js. Thanks again